# MVC RedirectToAction and XMLHttpRequest send

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest

I have a form which can contain files and it shows a progress bar successfully. My problem is that in the MVC Controller I have:

```
return RedirectToAction("Complete", new { title = title });
```

This goes and executes the Complete method if I step through but it then goes back to the JavaScript load event and does not redirect me unless I add a JavaScript redirect in the load event listener (uploadComplete):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
xhr.open("POST", "/Submit-Recipe", true);
xhr.send(fd);

function uploadComplete(evt) { 
//var valueFromController = how do I get a value here?;       
//window.location.replace("http://@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["website"]/SubmitRecipeComplete/" + valueFromTheController);
}
```

Is there a way to not have to add a JavaScript redirect? If I do need a JavaScript redirect, how can I pass a variable back from the controller when it needs to be an ActionResult (for if there is an error and I need to redisplay the page?).

I can work around this by adding a second page where I could know the "valueFromController" but 2 forms breaks the workflow a bit.

**EDIT**

I did what Praveen said but GetData() did not work for me so I used this instead:

```
evt.currentTarget.responseText
```

To determine if to return the View or Content I added this just before xhr.send(fd);

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
```

In the controller I can then do:

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    return Content(title);
}
```

Comment: RedirectToAction is only used by the controller, it does not return a redirect to the web browser, ie HTTP 302 or HTTP 301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Class myContoller:controller
{
     public ActionResult MyAction()
     {
     bool isWantToRedirect;

     if(isWantToRedirect)
     {
       return Content('redirect');
     }
     else
     {
          return View(); 
     }
}



function uploadComplete(evt) { 

 var valueFromController = evt.GetData();

  if(valueFromController=="redirect")
  {
     //redirect
  }
  else
  {
     //do not redirect, do something else
   }
}
```